# Vuex modules for Async data in multiple places

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have hard time to understand how to use Vuex correctly, and if I even should to use it in my case.

Let's say I have simple online shop build from components:

1. Products list.
2. Products filtering.

#### Without Vuex:

I can make Filtering as child component and List as parent component. Fetch async data in List and then pass it as prop (or v-model) to Filtering. Then it can pass back filtered products by $emit. And it works fine.

### With Vuex:

Make Vuex store with module Products. Inside it all logic for fetching products from API and filtering it.
Now components List and Filtering can be separated. Inside them use getters/actions from store with Products module.
And it will work fine.

Do I understand it correctly?

#### But there is problem:

Let's say I wanna use Products API somewhere else, for example show couple recommended products.
Without Vuex it will be simple. Just make separate component that will fetch recommended data.

But if I understand correctly main point of using Vuex is sharing data globally. So how can I have two separate lists from same Vuex Module? So when user will choose something in Filters it should filter only main list, and not recommended products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the implementation.

For example, if you are using the API to pull all the data, and then filter client-side, then it would make sense to use vuex, since your components would update the filter and get the result. In the diagram below, `load products` is an asynchronous call that loads all the data, and then the application is making the relevant filtering specific to the component and potentially making it available to other compnents.

[image]

If you are making a call every time the filter changes and don't need to persist or share the data between components, there may be little benefit to using it.

Note that vuex is a tool which helps with managing global state, it's up to you to decide whether the data in your app benefits from utilizing it.